# make git-diff ignore new lines

Tags: git, git-diff

I am modifying a long-ish text manuscript, putting one sentence per line, where before I had one paragraph per line.

I would like to carefully check (using git-diff) that I made no mistakes. Which git-diff command would tell me there is no difference between these two:

```
(before:)
This is the first sentence. This is the second sentence.

(after:)
This is the first sentence.
This is the second sentence.
```

Comment: If that is the *only* change you're making, you could run both versions of the text through something that simply strips whitespace and newlines (`tr -d '[:blank:]\n'`) and then calculate a checksum of the resulting data; if it matches, you have only introduced whitespace/newline changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`--word-diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---word-diffltmodegt). It's usually used to see small changes in long lines.

By default it uses whitespace to delimit words, as a side-effect it ignores whitespace changes.

Newline-only changes will still show up as hunks, but there will be no highlighted change. You can use [`-U0`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt--Ultngt) to reduce these to just a change marker.

If you just want to see if anything changed, you can use the various [`--stat`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---statltwidthgtltname-widthgtltcountgt) options.

---

If you have a non-Git diff program which does what you want, you can use it with [`git-difftool`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool).

Comment: This works, although one has to look through the full text to see highlighted differences. But much better than no diff at all!

Comment: @mspices Try adding `-U0`. This removes context from the changed hunks. You'll still see there's a change, but there will be no text. Also be sure to use color to highlight the changes.

Comment: I like it! And using `word-diff=plain` I can search for the differences marked `{+added+}` and `{-removed-}`.